# Find value for a key in a string

Tags: oracle, parsing, stored-procedures, plsql

Query:

```
Select searchtext from xyz.
```

Result

```
searchtext
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
serviceID 100615188 accessID 100615187 accessPathSpeed 5Mbps handoverID 100556732 accessSpeed 5Mbps
```

In this I want serviceID as column name and 100615188 as value.
like

```
ServiceID
-----------
100556732
```

Comment: Your expected output is shown incorrectly. You said - *serviceID as column name and 100615188* and then in the expected output, you are displaying 100556732 which is actually handoverId

Comment: Let's clarify the requirement. Your input string may have many pairs - you are ONLY searcing for ServiceID, and not for any other pair/column/attribute, correct? You may have many rows in the input, if you only have one column in the output how do you differentiate them? Is there also a separate id column in your inputs, to serve as primary key, and if so shouldn't it also be in the output? Then - what if there is more than one ServiceID in your input string? What if there is none? (If these situations are not possible in your data, please say so.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to solve this:

```
select regexp_replace(col,'.*serviceID\s+(\d+).*','\1') from your_table;
```

Demo:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
SQL> with your_table(col) as (
  2    select 'serviceID 100615188 accessID 100615187 accessPathSpeed 5Mbps handoverID 100556732 accessSpeed 5Mbps' from dual
  3  )
  4  select
  5    regexp_replace(col,'.*serviceID\s+(\d+).*','\1') serviceId
  6  from your_table;

SERVICEID
---------
100615188

SQL>
```

Details:

```
'.*serviceID\s+(\d+).*'
```

- `.*` - Match zero or more character before `serviceID`
- `serviceID` - match the text literally
- `\s+` - match 1 or more whitespace character after `serviceID`
- `()` - to build a capturing group
- `\d+` - match 1 or more digits

and in the replace part

- `\1` - replace the whole match with the first captured group using backreferencing.

If the serviceId is always going to be the first integer part in the string, then you can also use `regexp_substr`:

```
select
  regexp_substr(col,'\d+') serviceId
from your_table;
```

Comment: regexp_substr(SEARCHTEXT,'[^ ]+',INSTR(upper(SEARCHTEXT),'SERVICENAME',1),2)AS service_name